# (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

#I am trying to detect face and eyes using HAAR cascade and then save the crop images in new folder, code worked for singles images however not working in function. Any suggestion?

Here is the code :

```
    def get_cropped_image_if_2_eyes(image_path):
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            if len(eyes) >=2:
                return roi_color
cropped_image_dirs =[]
celebrity_file_names_dict = {}

for img_dir in img_dirs:
    celebrity_name = img_dir.split('/')[-1]
    for entry in os.scandir(img_dir):
        roi_color = get_cropped_image_if_2_eyes(entry.path)
        if roi_color is not None:
            cropped_folder = path_to_cr_data + celebrity_name
            if not os.path.exists(cropped_folder):
                os.makedirs(cropped_folder)
                print("Generating cropped images in folder:",cropped_folder)
```

Comment: What that says is that file in `image_path` did not exist.  Show us the code that CALLS this code.

Comment: I think i am getting error here ("roi_color = get_cropped_image_if_2_eyes(entry.path))

Comment: path_to_data =  "model/dataset/"
import os
img_dirs = []
for entry in os.scandir(path_to_data):
    if entry.is_dir():
        img_dirs.append(entry.path)

Comment: and welcome. please take the [tour] and you might find these articles interesting: [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that every file in this folder is an image?  Have you done `print(image_path)` so you can verify what file it is trying to open?